# Создание метода, который не передается объекту

Tags: objective-c

Возник вопрос - как создать метод, который не вызывается у объекта:
`[myObject myMethod:params];`

а который просто принимает аргументы и что-то возвращает:
`myObject = myMethod(params)`

Это иногда удобно с точки зрения читаемости кода. Например метод `CGRectMake` так и делает - принимает `GGFloat` и возвращает `CGRect`.

Comment: С objectiva-c не знаком, но насколько я понимаю вам нужен метод который будет работать только внутри класса(объекта). В java для этой цели есть контроль доступа. К примеру метод можно пометить как private. Тогда запись такого типа object.method(); вне класса не будет работать. Но если вызвать данный метод внутри класса например method(); то всё заработает. Копайте в сторону контроля доступа.

Comment: Вам небось нужна обыкновенная сишная функция. (Ну или «плюсовый» метод, может быть.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGRectMake - сишная функция.

Ну запишите свою функцию на си.

Например:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions     {

NSString* string = @"123";
BOOL myString = stringEmpty(string);
NSLog(@"%d", myString);
return YES;

}

BOOL stringEmpty(NSString* string) {

    if (string.length > 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: И таким образом мне не нужен будет объект, чтобы вызвать этот метод?

Comment: Как видите да. Вы немного плаваете в ООП. Почитайте про классы и методы.